# How to format as code in Stack Exchange mobile app

Tags: support, code-formatting, mobile-app

How to write code when asking a question in the Stack Exchange mobile app?
For example, on the computer, we arrange code by just pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.
What should I do in the mobile app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Stack Exchange app, there is a 'format' button for this purpose above your keyboard. First, select the piece of text you want to indent by four spaces; then, click the button.

```
Test
Test
Test
```

[image]
[image]